# How to group the dates from array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, nsarray

My date formate is “2019-12-03T05:58:11.317Z” like this. I want to group the same date elements. And i can create UITableView sections based on dates. This is array i have three different dates so i want to create 3 sections. Here the **problem** is **newArrayList** not saving all the elements.

```
        NSMutableArray * arrayList;
        NSMutableArray *newArrayList;
        //This is my date array
        arrayList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@“2019-12-03T05:58:11.317Z”, @“2019-12-03T05:58:10.317Z”, @“2019-12-03T05:58:01.317Z”, @“2019-12-03T05:55:12.448Z”, @“2019-12-03T05:48:11.317Z”, @“2019-12-03T05:28:11.317Z”, @“2019-12-03T05:11:24.004Z”, @“2019-12-03T05:28:11.317Z”, @“2019-12-03T05:55:12.965Z”, @“2019-12-02T15:09:35.408Z”, @“2019-12-02T15:09:38.187Z”, @“2019-12-02T15:43:02.118Z”, @“2019-12-02T15:44:09.344Z”, @“2019-12-02T17:07:55.038Z”, @“2019-12-02T16:42:16.649Z”, @“2019-12-01T16:42:16.649Z”, nil];

        newArrayList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];//Here I want to same date elements 

            NSDate *fromDate;
            NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            for (int i=0; i<arrayList.count; i++) {
                NSDate *dt1 = fromDate;
                NSDate *dt2 = [self getLocalDateTimeFromUTC2:[arrayList objectAtIndex:i]];
                if (i != 0) {
                    if ([self isSameDay:dt1 otherDay:dt2] == YES) {
                        [tempArray addObject:t];
                    } else {
                        [newArrayList addObject:tempArray];
                    //  [tempArray removeAllObjects];
                    }
                }
                fromDate = dt2;
            }

//To get required date formate
-(NSDate *)getLocalDateTimeFromUTC2:(NSString *)strDate
{

// create dateFormatter with UTC time format
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ"]; //@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ"
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
//    NSLog(@"%@", t.dateAndTime); //2019-12-02T15:09:38.187Z
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strDate]; // create date from string

// change to a readable time format and change to local time zone
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
NSString *timestamp = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
NSDate *date2 = [dateFormat dateFromString:timestamp];
//    NSLog(@"%@", date2);

return date2;
}

//To compare two dates
- (BOOL)isSameDay:(NSDate*)date1 otherDay:(NSDate*)date2 {

NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
unsigned unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth |  NSCalendarUnitDay;
NSDateComponents* comp1 = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date1];
NSDateComponents* comp2 = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date2];
return [comp1 day]   == [comp2 day] && [comp1 month] == [comp2 month] && [comp1 year]  == [comp2 year];
}
```

Comment: **newArrayList** saving only last group, i want to save all the groups.

Comment: Hows your actual data looks like. I mean you wanted to group same group of dates, but what you will show in rows? Is date is coming as array of string or in array of dict?

Comment: I will show same day dates in section wise and in geader i will show that day. Like call log.

Comment: Means in section you will show date and in row you will show time?

Comment: @ dahiya_boy, no in section i will show only that specific group date, in rows i will show all dates with time one by one.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictByDate = [NSMutableDictionary new];
NSMutableArray *newArr = [NSMutableArray new] ;

for(NSString *strDate in arrayList)
{

    // convert date to proper formate (if needed)

    NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ"];
    NSDate *dateNew = [format dateFromString:strDate];
    [format setDateFormat:@"MMMM-dd-yyyy"];
    NSString *finalDateString = [format stringFromDate:dateNew];

    NSLog(@"%@",finalDateString) ;

    NSMutableArray *arrWithSameDate = dictByDate[finalDateString];
    if(! arrWithSameDate)
    {
        arrWithSameDate = [NSMutableArray new];
        dictByDate[finalDateString] = arrWithSameDate;
    }
    [arrWithSameDate addObject: strDate];

}

[newArr addObjectsFromArray:[dictByDate allValues]] ;

NSLog(@"group data: %@", newArr);
```

Comment: can i expect output like array of arrays form this code.

Comment: output like: ["November 28, 2019": ["November 28, 2019", "November 28, 2019 "], "November 29, 2019": ["November 29, 2019", "November 29, 2019", "November 29, 2019"], "November 30, 2019": ["November 30, 2019 "]]

Comment: [[03-12-2019 12, 03-12-2019 12, 03-12-2019 12], [02-12-2019 12, 02-12-2019 12, 02-12-2019 12], [01-12-2019 12]];  this is enough

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing in swift, hope you will manage in obj-c

---

1. **Assuming you have below data**

   ```
   let arrDates = [  "2019-12-03T05:58:11.317Z ",   "2019-12-03T05:58:10.317Z ",   "2019-12-03T05:58:01.317Z ",   "2019-12-03T05:55:12.448Z ",   "2019-12-03T05:48:11.317Z ",   "2019-12-03T05:28:11.317Z ",   "2019-12-03T05:11:24.004Z ",   "2019-12-03T05:28:11.317Z ",   "2019-12-03T05:55:12.965Z ",   "2019-12-02T15:09:35.408Z ",   "2019-12-02T15:09:38.187Z ",   "2019-12-02T15:43:02.118Z ",   "2019-12-02T15:44:09.344Z ",   "2019-12-02T17:07:55.038Z ",   "2019-12-02T16:42:16.649Z ",   "2019-12-01T16:42:16.649Z "]
   ```
2. **Make group of date**

   ```
   let dictGroupDate = Dictionary(grouping: arrDates) { (strdate) -> String in
   let df = DateFormatter()
   df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ"
   let date = df.date(from: strdate)
   df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
   return df.string(from: date!)
   }
   ```
3. **Get all section dates and sort them**

   ```
   let arrDateKey = Array(dictGroupDate.keys).sorted { (strdate1, strdate2) -> Bool in
   let df = DateFormatter()
   df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
   let date1 = df.date(from: strdate1)
   let date2 = df.date(from: strdate2)

   return date1!.compare(date2!)  == .orderedAscending
   }
   ```
4. **sort time for every date and create new dict**

   ```
    var newGroupedDates = [String : [String]]()

   for strKey in arrDateKey {
   let sortedTime = dictGroupDate[strKey]?.sorted(by: { (strdate1, strdate2) -> Bool in
       let df = DateFormatter()
       df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ"
       let date1 = df.date(from: strdate1)
       let date2 = df.date(from: strdate2)

       return date1!.compare(date2!)  == .orderedAscending

     })

   newGroupedDates[strKey] = sortedTime!
   }
   ```
5. **Show data in `UITABLEVIEW`**

   ```
   // NumberOfSections
   arrDateKey.count

   //NumberOfRows
   let key = arrDateKey[indexPath.section]
   newGroupedDates[key]?.count

   // CellForRow
   // To get correct date and Time

   let key = arrDateKey[indexPath.section]
   let item = newGroupedDates[key]![indexPath.row]
    // Now item is the date string, and do whatever you wanted to do.
   ```

**Output**

Final newGroupedDates

```
["2019-12-03": ["2019-12-03T05:11:24.004Z ", "2019-12-03T05:28:11.317Z ", "2019-12-03T05:28:11.317Z ", "2019-12-03T05:48:11.317Z ", "2019-12-03T05:55:12.448Z ", "2019-12-03T05:55:12.965Z ", "2019-12-03T05:58:01.317Z ", "2019-12-03T05:58:10.317Z ", "2019-12-03T05:58:11.317Z "], "2019-12-02": ["2019-12-02T15:09:35.408Z ", "2019-12-02T15:09:38.187Z ", "2019-12-02T15:43:02.118Z ", "2019-12-02T15:44:09.344Z ", "2019-12-02T16:42:16.649Z ", "2019-12-02T17:07:55.038Z "], "2019-12-01": ["2019-12-01T16:42:16.649Z "]]
```

---

In case, I missed something then comment me.

Comment: can you please write in objective c

Comment: I want to save only date arrays in **finaldatearray**, that's enough. I don't want dictionay type. I can fetch each section first object date and i will show on header.

Comment: thank you . If possible please post objective code and espically i want out put like array of array's.

Comment: @iOS As you mentioned, you wanted to show dates in row, in that case you need to do all code. If in case you want only sections then you can do upto point 3. If you do not want sorting then do `let arrDateKey = Array(dictGroupDate.keys)` in point 3.

Comment: I afraid, array of array won't change the index, but you can try in step 4. Do `var newArray = [[String]]()` and inside for loop instead of setting dict, do `newArray.append(sortedTime)`

Answer (score 0):

some notes: 
1) do not keep dates as strings, for many reasons:
a) Date use less memory
b) you can compare and sort  using but in functions that take in account timezones and leaps.

2) do not create formatters in every place (i.e. put therm out of for)
as per Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW10